# How to weight income by population in F#?

Tags: f#

My data is below. There are three columns that I use, and I want to be able to weight the income, by how many people make that income. There are multiple instances of State, because each income is in a different band. For example:

```
State   Income    Pop

AL      45000     8500
AL      78000     7800
AL      80000     1200
TX      500000    500
TX      100000    700
TX      40000     8000
MO      100000    7000
MO      780000    1000
MO      79000     1500
```

I want to weight income by the number of people out of the population that is in the band of income.

So for AL, I need:

```
45000 * 8500/(8500+7800+1200) + 
78000 * 7800/(8500+7800+1200) + 
80000 * 1200/(8500+7800+1200)    =  The Total <- this is the number I need, PER State
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
type Data = 
    {State : string
     Income : float
     Pop : float }

let data = 
    [{State="AL"; Income=45000.; Pop=8500.};
     {State="AL"; Income=78000.; Pop=7800.};
     {State="AL"; Income=80000.; Pop=1200.};
     {State="TX"; Income=500000.;Pop= 500.};
     {State="TX"; Income=100000.;Pop= 700.};
     {State="TX"; Income=40000.; Pop=8000.};
     {State="MO"; Income=100000.;Pop= 7000.};
     {State="MO"; Income=780000.;Pop= 1000.};
     {State="MO"; Income=79000.; Pop=1500.} ]

data 
|> List.map(fun r -> r.State) 
|> List.distinct
|> List.map (fun state ->
    let stateRecords = data |> List.filter (fun r -> r.State = state)
    let statePopulation= stateRecords |> List.map (fun r -> r.Pop) |> List.sum
    let avg = stateRecords |> List.map (fun r -> r.Income * r.Pop / statePopulation) |> List.sum
    (state, avg)
    )
```

Comment: what if I wanted to add a region variable along with state and average? Could I include that in the first `List.map`? But the region would not be distinct, because many states can be in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
data
|> List.groupBy (fun x -> x.State)
|> List.map
    (fun (state, grp) ->
        let n, d = 
            List.fold 
                (fun (n, d) v -> 
                    n + v.Pop *  v.Income, d + v.Pop) 
                (0.0, 0.0) grp 
        state, n / d)
```

If your data is sorted by state I guess it may be better for performance to use some fold function "right away" instead of call `groupBy` first.